# Playing fullscreen video on iPhone without any user controls or interaction?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, uiview

I'm working on an iOS game that has an intro video. How do I play the video full screen without:

1) user controls like play/pause being visible

2) touches like double-tap or pinching changing the video's scale/zoom?

To disable taps on the video, can I just add a blank UIView overtop of the movie player view? How would I do that?

Comment: >>>To disable taps on the video, can I just add a blank UIView overtop of the movie player view? How would I do that?
That might work.
Try to re-associate the event handlers thru notifications or just raw delegate methods and just overrite those methods for handling multitouch gestures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with adding a "blank" view overtop the MPMoviePlayerController.  This is how I set it up. Didn't have to mess with event handlers.

```
mBlankView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
mBlankView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[mBlankView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[mBlankView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[window addSubview:mBlankView];
```

viewFrame contains the size of the MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 5):

What kind of movie player are you using?
If you're using MPMoviePlayerViewController/MPMoviePlayerController you can set the controlStyle property to MPMovieControlStyleNone.
(If you use MPMoviePlayerViewController you first call the moviePlayer property so you get the MPMoviePlayerController which has the controlStyle property)

Example:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayerViewController = [MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"XYZ" ofType:@"mp4"]]];
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:NO completion:nil];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
player.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;   //hide the controls
[player play];
```